# Prestashop blocklayered reloadContent() returns wrong language

Tags: prestashop

I have a problem using prestashop with blocklayered module, my shop's default language is French (id_lang = 1).

Here are the steps to get to the error:
I switch to English (id_lang = 4) and go to the product list page, all the products are written in English, no problem here.
Then, each time I try to use blocklayered filters, all the results returned are written in French instead of English.

I added var_dumps in the header and on the product-list.tpl to see the value of $cookie->id_lang. They are both set to 4 (English language). After using blocklayered, I still have the id_lang to 4 in header BUT, the one that is in product-list is now set to 1 which is the french id_lang.

PS version: 1.6.1.0

Blocklayered version: 2.1.3

Comment: I have the same problem in 2020… Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reloadContent() function in /modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.php calls the following function:

ajaxCall() in /modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.php

This function is using $cookie->id_lang to fetch the current language ID, try debugging the value of this variable.

You can also try replacing it with $this->context->language->id, it might fix your issue.

Comment: I tried to go all through the code and I have no idea why it is calling the `Tools::switchLanguage()` function.

The code is using `Tools::getValue('id_lang')` (which is `$_GET['id_lang']` in that case).